# Is there a more efficient way to take the values from one row and apply it to the next 'n' rows in the same column? Pandas

Tags: python, performance, pandas

Say I have a dataframe. The dataframe has three columns foo1, foo2, fooName, and has 4,000 rows. In every 5th row there is a value in fooName 'blah'. I want to go through the dataframe and say when fooName equals 'blah', then the next 4 values (those that aren't filled with the blah value) of foo1 are set to the value of foo1 where fooName equaled 'blah'.

I have been able to get this to work by doing the following:

```
i = 0
while i is <= len(dataframe):
    if dataframe[fooName].values[i] = 'blah':
        x = i + 5
        dataframe['foo1'][i:x] = dataframe['foo1'].values[i]
    else:
        i = i + 1
return dataframe
```

This works, but its very slow. Is there any way to do this but in a more efficient way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC then the following should work

```
dataframe.loc[dataframe['fooname'] !='blah', 'foo1'] = np.NaN
dataframe['foo1'] = dataframe['foo1'].ffill()
```

So you can replace the rows where the condition is not met with `NaN` and then call `ffill` to forward fill the values

Comment: This solution wasn't obvious to me, but totally makes sense.  Nice trick to remember.